# Binary Search Tree not sorting properly/not following my order

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am trying to create a Binary Search Tree (BST) for a really large txt file (around 150000 lines), but my BST is not sorting properly. My current theory is, when I fetch the key from the txt file, it doesn't register properly, making it fetch a random number from memory. Other than that, I have no idea whats wrong.

NOTE: the txt file has the following format (key on left, value on right)

```
0016718719    #:@-;QZL=!9v
0140100781    5:`ziuiCMMUC
0544371484    W{<_|b5Qd534
0672094320    QcvX=;[lpR("
0494074201    FB[?T5VHc7Oc
0317651971    K`9@Qn{@h]1z
0635368102    KGVm-?hX{Rv7
0107206064    =n1AsY32_.J9
0844660357    L4qL)x{>5e8H
0699014627    v/<4%"sJ4eHR
0786095462    G!cl'YMAL*@S
0067578317    6{"W,j2>@{p*
0730012647    rAi?q<X5NaKT
0715302988    ,8SrSw0rEEc&
0234601050    PRg$$:b|B0'x
0537081097    fgoDc05rc,n|
0226858124    OV##d6th'<us
1059497442    2,'n}YmK,s^i
0597822915    LhicQ#r<Yh\8
0742176394    g`XkLi.>}s+Q
0984120927    DyB:-u*}E&X)
0202768627    8(&zqlPV@DCb
0089402669    tv-vTkn"AIxt
1045610730    hOxZQ<"yyew`
0671297494    )r7gD;:9FHrq
0245267004    f0oO:/Zul0<"
0766946589    n/03!]3t0Lux
0521860458    _D+$,j#YT$cS
0891617938    t%gYiWV17Z/'
0566759626    r2A'PB'xhfw@
0221374897    e[-Nf"@<o9^p
0428608071    46S4!vZA.S&.
0755431241    mgE?2IewG!=g
0534588781    %P|b"_d'VF0S
0030447903    Q&Dow27tkc9+
0957065636    [pHMrM*q*ED7
0739800529    wR;u\Ct/-Vzo
0556668090    =|T.z]?.:DnC
0649777919    2}5M=.u'@1,L
0464018855    x+JImm6w/eG]
0460707117    lxY}\Cdn%!rs
0273053706    s9GmIAE."j|2
0596408906    %'1|R%3tI-Tz
0473143619    k,h&_7rT)?Nb
0922139211    [e0Q1].<Qb;[
0207160144    t!&lXR7`eW#n
0128147823    L,d'7]ZTvPDQ
0178779865    (&--sQ..)7d'
0531711943    4o'^xS6rK]yl
0429655621    eyd7UwKQ][%i
0566959905    k{)d*OH&w2P<
0472331841    DiZF(W"wO42H
0589473577    V0$9-X%YD_kD
0272100993    i%c&R{^#SM$@
0956804045    BtY'cQ){wR{{
0635780805    dWnP0sP2]Tu[
0874803681    swn\*HS08v<w
1027292189    w#E:LaCg(L(I
0592836099    ]&Q({r^(/H%0
0882899568    zb_4acX8E<2-
0542667063    n'xbSaoXArp6
0289624942    G5X#aqr7+*pb
0682188682    H^o)>1\4o5WV
0984355947    =Z{wmP'Z(@2r
0459720821    1vNg_4`3IUUJ
0563538441    uA>QKi]Z31#x
1032927818    $jReN<b/(e{E
0299897321    j=PAkNj#H(L^
0428967901    8lszH<!m\C`w
0668128293    SO("{Rm29l@Y
0354915591    2coM%<Iiwwn<
0672908146    r3VRE;Q3)zi>
0435139431    d_q_)mM"X]N-
0728369037    >X_!}vtc;G(M
0982520682    {h\5gbvzsqGZ
0396776915    $py=A?iNde7(
0511806860    #T+Y0HI9/U6K
0013335601    <$8f|iV\=/RD
0511264736    NFI-#xssP)F*
0727884351    5ZMcmA0[K3P2
0460487630    .D'h(f"LV]@x
0178037927    o3a&fO}="I.S
```

Here is my Main file:

```
#include "LAB3BST2.h"
#include <string.h>

#define HEIGHT_WRITTEN  1
#define FINDPARENTHELPER_WRITTEN    1
#define DELETE_WRITTEN  1
#define LOOKUP_written 1

int digit(char *key) {
    int number = 0;//create a

    while (*key != '\0') {//loop until the end of the string (number)
        number = 10 * number + *key - '0';//(10*number) this represents moving the current value of key one up
        //(*key - '0') the current char subtracted by '0' or the value of 48
        // example: (char '1') - '0' == int 1. Reference ASCII chart to see hexadecimal logic
        *key++;
    }
    return number;
}

int main(void) {
    Node *n = NULL;        // eliminates compiler warning
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    Tree *t = NULL;
    char *pbuff = (char *)malloc(256);
    char *p, *key, *pass;
    int temp = 0;
    long bst_node = 0;

    fp = fopen("IDENTS.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("File Open Failed\n");
        return 0;
    }//initialize the head of the tree

    while (1) {
        p = fgets(pbuff, 256, fp);
        if (p == NULL)
            break; //memory not allocated, or end of file
        while (*p == ' ')
            p++; //if spaces, iterate through string
        key = p;
        p++;
        while ((*p) >= 48 && (*p) <= 57)
            p++;//if a digit character (47<p<58 or 0-9), iterate through key
        *p = '\0';//null everything after the key (digits)
        p++; //iterate onto the password
        while (*p == ' ')
            p++;//if spaces, iterate through string
        pass = p;
        p++;
        while ((*p) != '\r' && (*p) != '\n') {
            p++;
        }// iterate until the end of the string ('\n')
        *p = '\0';//null the rest, and reset "p"
        temp = digit(key);
        if (temp < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (temp == 170696526) {
            //nothing
        }
        if (t == NULL) {
            t = initTree(temp, pass);
        } else
            insert(temp, pass, t->root);//WE NEED TO BE ABLE TO CREATE A PASS THAT DOES NOT CHANGE
        bst_node++;
    }
    printf("\nBST NODES: %ld", bst_node);
    fclose(fp);

    /*
    printf("Original Tree: \n");
    printTree(t->root);
    printf("\n\n");

    if (HEIGHT_WRITTEN == 1) {
        printf("Height of tree: %d\n\n", height(t->root));
    }
*/

    if (DELETE_WRITTEN == 1) {
        FILE *fp_del;
        fp_del = fopen("DELETES.txt", "r");
        while (1) {
            p = fgets(pbuff, 256, fp_del);
            if (p == NULL)
                break;
            while (*p == ' ')
                p++;
            key = p;
            p++;
            while (*p != '\r' && *p != '\n') {
                p++;
            }
            *p = '\0';
            int k = withdraw(digit(key), t->root);
            if (k) 
                bst_node--;
        }
    }
    printf("\nNODES AFTER DELETES: %ld \n", bst_node);
    if (!bst_check(t->root))
        printf("NOT BST\n");
    else
        printf("IS A BST\n");

    if (LOOKUP_written) {
        FILE *fp_look;
        fp_look = fopen("LOOKUPS.txt", "r");
        int nnkey = 0;
        while (1) {
            p = fgets(pbuff, 256, fp_look);
            if (p == NULL)
                break;
            while (*p == ' ')
                p++;
            key = p;
            p++;
            while (*p != '\r' && *p != '\n') {
                p++;
            }
            *p = '\0';
            nnkey = digit(key);
            Node* k = find(nnkey, t->root);
            if (!k) {
                printf("ID: %13d PASSWORD: <NOT FOUND>\n", nnkey);
            } else {
                printf("ID: %13d PASSWORD: %s\n", nnkey, k->value);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}//main()
```

Here is my function file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "LAB3BST2.h"

Node *initNode(Key k, char *v)
// Allocate memory for new node and initialize fields.
// Returns pointer to node created.
{
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    // initialize node if memory obtained
    if (n != NULL) {
        n->key = k;
        n->value = strdup(v);
        n->leftChild = NULL;
        n->rightChild = NULL;
    }
    return n;
}//initNode()

Tree *initTree(Key k, char *v)
// Set up new tree. Allocates memory for Tree structure, then
// calls initNode() to allocate first node.
{
    Tree *t = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    if (t != NULL)
        t->root = initNode(k, v);
    return t;
}//initTree()

void printTreeExplanation(void)
// Prints hint to reader what to expect on screen
{
    static int done = 0;
    if (!done) {
        printf("First time explanation of tree display:\n");
        printf("Every node is displayed as a comma-separated pair within brackets:");
        printf(" (kk,vv)\n");
        printf("where kk is the key and vv is the value\n");
        printf("A tree starts with a curly bracket { and ends with a curly bracket }.\n");
        printf("An empty tree will be {}\n");
        printf("A tree with no children will be { (kk,vv),{},{} }\n");
        printf("If either subtree is populated, it will be shown using the same ");
        printf("technique as described above\n");
        printf("(Hint: Start at root - and then match up all the remaining\n");
        printf("brackets, then interpret what those bracket pairs are telling\n");
        printf("you.)\n============\n\n");
        done = 1;
    }
}//printTreeExplanation()

void printTree(Node *root)
// Print whole tree. We cannot make it look pretty graphically, so we add some
// characters to make it a little easier to understand.  We also don't really
// know what the value field is - it is declared to be a void pointer - so we
// treat it as though it points to an integer.
{
    // assume printTree magically knows the types in the tree node
    printTreeExplanation();
    // start of this tree
    printf("{");
    // values in the root node (assuming value is pointing to an integer)
    printf("(%d,%s),", root->key, root->value);

    // Now show left subtree or {} if there is no left subtree
    if (root->leftChild != NULL)
        printTree(root->leftChild);
    else
        printf("{}");
    // Marker between left and right subtrees
    printf(",");
    // Now show right subtree or {} if there is no right subtree
    if (root->rightChild != NULL)
        printTree(root->rightChild);
    else
        printf("{}");
    // Close display of this tree with closing curly bracket
    printf("}");
}//printTree()

Node *find(Key k, Node *root)
{
    // termination conditions - either true, search is ended
    if ((root == NULL) || (root->key == k))
        return root;
    if (k > root->key)      //traverse through the right subtree (larger)
        return find(k, root->rightChild);
    else                    //traverse through the right
        return find(k, root->leftChild);
}//find()

int insert(Key k, char *v, Node *root)
{
    int result = BST_FAIL;
    // this if statement can only be true with first root (root of whole tree)
    if (root == NULL) {
        Node *n = initNode(k, v);
        root = n;
        return BST_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (root->key == k)
        root->value = strdup(v);//replace password
    else
    if (k < root->key) {
        // key value less than key value in root node - try to insert into left
        // subtree, if it exists.
        if (root->leftChild != NULL)
            // there is a left subtree - insert it
            result = insert(k, v, root->leftChild);
        else {
            // new Node becomes the left subtree
            Node *n = initNode(k, v);
            root->leftChild = n;
            result = BST_SUCCESS;
        }
    } else
    if (k > root->key) {            // test actually redundant
        // key is greater than this nodes key value, so value goes into right
        // subtree, if it exists
        if (root->rightChild != NULL)
            // there is a right subtree - insert new node
            result = insert(k, v, root->rightChild);
        else {
            // no right subtree - new node becomes right subtree
            Node *n = initNode(k, v);
            root->rightChild = n;
            result = BST_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return result;
}//insert()

int intmax(int a, int b) {
    return (a >= b) ? a : b;
}//intmax()

int height(Node *root)
// Height definition:
// Height of an empty tree is -1.  Height of a leaf node is 0. Height of other
// nodes is 1 more than larger height of node's two subtrees.
{
    int nodeheight = -1;
    int right, left;// default returned for empty tree
    if (root != NULL) {
        left = height(root->leftChild);
        right = height(root->rightChild);
        nodeheight = intmax(left, right);
    }
    return nodeheight;
}//height()

Node *findParentHelper(Key k, Node *root)
// Help find parent of node with key == k. Parameter root is node with
// at least one child (see findParent()).
{
    if (root->leftChild != NULL) {
        if (root->leftChild->key == k)
            return root;
    }
    if (root->rightChild != NULL) {
        if (root->rightChild->key == k)
            return root;
    }
    if (k > root->key)
        return findParentHelper(k, root->rightChild);
    else
        return findParentHelper(k, root->leftChild);
}//findparenthelper()

Node *findParent(Key k, Node *root)
// root
{
    // Deal with special special cases which could only happen for root
    // of whole tree
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    // real root doesn't have parent so we make it parent of itself
    if (root->key == k)
        return root;
    // root has no children
    if ((root->leftChild == NULL) && (root->rightChild == NULL))
        return NULL;

    // Deal with cases where root has at least one child
    return findParentHelper(k, root);
}//findParent()

Node *findMin(Node *root) {
    if (root->leftChild == NULL)
        return root;
    return findMin(root->leftChild);
}

Node *findMax(Node *root) {
    if (root->rightChild == NULL)
        return root;
    return findMax(root->rightChild);
}

int check(Node *p, Node *n) {
    if (p->rightChild == n)
        return 1; //1==right, 0==left
    return 0;
}

void delete(Node *p, Node *n)
// Delete node pointed to by n.
// Parameters:
//  n   - points to node to be deleted
//  p   - points to parent of node to be deleted.
{
    // Deletion has 3 cases - no subtrees, only left or right subtree, or both
    // left and right subtrees.
    if (p == n) { //if the root is the node to be deleted
        Node *temp;
        int key;
        char *pass;
        if (p->rightChild) {
            temp = findMin(p->rightChild);
            key = temp->key;
            pass = strdup(temp->value);
            delete(findParent(temp->key, n), temp);
            p->key = key;
            p->value = pass;
        } else
        if (p->leftChild) {
            temp = findMax(p->leftChild);
            key = temp->key;
            pass = strdup(temp->value);
            delete(findParent(temp->key, n), temp);
            p->key = key;
            p->value = pass;
        }
        return;
    }
    if (n->leftChild != NULL) {         // there is left child
        if (n->rightChild) {              //if both
            Node *temp = findMin(n->rightChild);
            n->key = temp->key;
            n->value = strdup(temp->value);
            delete(findParent(temp->key, n), temp);//delete the min value found (which is a leaf on the left most right branch)
        } else {                         //if only left
            if (check(p, n)) {
                p->rightChild = n->leftChild;
            } else
                p->leftChild = n->leftChild;
            free(n);
        }
    } else
    if (n->rightChild) {            // there is only a right child
        if (check(p, n)) {
            p->rightChild = n->rightChild;
        } else
            p->leftChild = n->rightChild;
        free(n);
    } else {// no children
        if (check(p, n)) {
            p->rightChild = NULL;
        } else
            p->leftChild = NULL;
        free(n);
    }
}//delete()

int withdraw(Key k, Node *root)
// Withdraw does two things:
//  return a copy of the node with key k (and value v)
//  Delete the node with key k from the tree while ensuring the tree remains valid
{
    Node *p, *m;
    m = find(k, root);

    if (m != NULL) {
        // create a copy of the node with the same key and value
        //n = initNode(m->key, m->value);
        p = findParent(k, root);
        // can delete the node
        delete(p, m);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}//withdraw()

int bst_check(Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return 1; // if on a leaf (return back up to root) //170696526
    if (root->leftChild != NULL && root->leftChild->key > root->key)
        //if the left child exists and its key is greater than the root
        return 0;

    if (root->rightChild != NULL && root->rightChild->key < root->key)
        // if the right child exists and is smaller than the root
        return 0;

    if (!bst_check(root->leftChild) || !bst_check(root->rightChild))
        //if the check was unsuccessful for both the right and left subtrees
        //also recursively checks the left and right child
        return 0;

    //if all pass, then the tree was a bst
    return 1;
}
```

Here is my function file (.h file):

```
// LAB3_BST.H 
// Header file to be used with code for ELEC278 Lab 3.
//
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int Key;

#define BST_FAIL    0       // return value when BST function fails
#define BST_SUCCESS 1       // return value when BST function succeeds

// Node in tree has key and pointer to value associated with key.
// Also contains structural components - two pointers to left and
// right subtrees.
typedef struct password {
    char *word;
    struct password *next;
} pnode;

typedef struct Node {
    Key key;
    char *value;
    struct Node *leftChild, *rightChild;
} Node, pNode;

// Tree is basically pointer to top node in a tree.
typedef struct Tree {
    Node *root;
} Tree;

Node *initNode(int k, char *v);

// Create new tree by creating new node with key = k and value = v
// and making it root
Tree *initTree(int k, char *v);

// Find node with key k in tree. Returns pointer to Node if found;
// Returns NULL if not found
Node *find(Key k, Node *root);

// Create new node with key=k, value=v and insert it into tree 
// Returns 1 upon success, 0 failure 
int insert(int k, char *v, Node *root);

// Print text representation of tree (starting at any Node)
void printTree(Node *root);

// Returns Maximum of two integer numbers 
int intmax(int a, int b);

// Find parent of node n where n->key = k
// Returns pointer to parent node if found; Returns NULL if not found
Node *findParent(Key k, Node *root);

// 1. Make copy of node with key=k and returns it
// 2. Delete node with key=k from tree
// Return pointer of node created in 1; Returns NULL if no node
// with specified key value is found
int withdraw(Key k, Node *root);

// Return height of tree (height of specified root)
int height(Node *root);

// Helper function for findParent - see specification in lab
// instructions
Node *findParentHelper(Key k, Node *root);

// Delete node from tree while ensuring tree remains valid
void delete(Node *p, Node *n);
Node* inorder(Node *pn);
int bst_check(Node *root);
```

I dont know where to start.

Comment: We don't know either. Have you tried breaking down this problem into smaller parts?

Comment: Indeed. _Minimal_ reproducible example.

Comment: I have tried breaking it down into a smaller problem. When I decrease the size of the folder to around 40 lines, the program is completely fine, but when I use the whole file the program breaks.

Comment: @LukaRodrigues: use a dichotomic approach: try half the size, then if it works, half again, otherwise add half of what you removed... in 17 steps you will have a file exactly the right size for the program to show the problem. Then you can use a debugger to analyse what kind of problem this last line causes.

Comment: `strdup()` may fail, and at least on Linux you need to define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 (or greater) or _POSIX_C_SOUCE 200809L.  In `insert()` you have `root = n` but then don't use root.  If you want to return a new value you need the argument to be `Node **root`.  In `main()` if !fp you leak pbuff.  You don't check if `fp_loop = fopen()` succeeds.

Comment: Also don't check fp_del.  Is the input a snippet of IDENTS.txt?

Comment: Does your input have any _duplicate_ keys? I cut out a whole bunch of crap from your code and constructed a minimal-ish example to demonstrate your program breaks when you insert a key that's already in the tree: https://godbolt.org/z/j37xrM5fc .. Oh, my bad, it might actually be breaking if the input doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: just noticed: this might fail for long strings: `while ((*p) != '\r' && (*p) != '\n') {` use `while(*p && ...`

Comment: Each line appears to be small and fixed length.

Comment: In digits *key++ is weird.  You probably just want key++.  Use a `for()` or scanf() instead of doing this yourself.  There is no error checking, say, if you key contains a non-number.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in function `insert`:

- if the `root` argument is NULL, the new node is just stored into the argument pointer and `BST_SUCCESS` is returned. The caller's node variable is not updated. This function should take the address of the `Node*` as an argument.  In your case, the tree is initialized as non empty, so this never occurs, but the tree will become empty after removing all elements and in this case, `insert` will always fail in spite of returning `BST_SUCCESS`.
- if `root->key == k`, a new value is allocated for this duplicate key, but the previous value is not freed, hence there is a memory leak.
- the test `else if (k > root->key)` is indeed redundant

Here is a modified and much simpler version:

```
int insert(Key k, const char *v, Node **np) {
    Node *node = *np;
    if (node == NULL) {
        *np = initNode(k, v);
        if (*np == NULL)
            return BST_FAIL;
        else
            return BST_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (k == node->key) {
        // node exists, replace password
        char *str = strdup(v);
        if (str == NULL) {
            return BST_FAIL;
        } else {
            free(node->value);
            node->value = str;
            return BST_SUCCESS;   // no new node, but insertion successful
        }
    }
    if (k < node->key) {
        // key value is less than key value in this node
        // insert it into left subtree, creating it if needed.
        return insert(k, v, &node->leftChild);
    } else {
        // key value is greater than key value in this node
        // insert it into right subtree, creating it if needed.
        return insert(k, v, &node->rightChild);
    }
}
```

Here is a non recursive version:

```
int insert(Key k, const char *v, Node **np) {
    while (*np) {
        Node *node = *np;
        if (k == node->key) {
            // node exists, replace password
            char *str = strdup(v);
            if (str == NULL) {
                return BST_FAIL;
            } else {
                free(node->value);
                node->value = str;
                return BST_SUCCESS;   // no new node, but insertion successful
            }
        }
        if (k < node->key) {
            // key value is less than key value in this node
            // insert it into left subtree, creating it if needed.
            np = &root->leftChild;
        } else {
            // key value is greater than key value in this node
            // insert it into right subtree, creating it if needed.
            np = &root->rightChild;
        }
    }
    *np = initNode(k, v);
    if (*np == NULL)
        return BST_FAIL;
    else
        return BST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note however that neither of the above functions implement a balanced tree (BST).  The tree needs rebalancing if the height of left and right child nodes' heights become too different.

Comment: How do you know fixing the first problems solves the issue?  I haven't checked yet but it seems the new root cause is avoided by using `initTree()`?

Comment: These issues are probably not the cause of the problem... I am posting remarks as I read the code, and there is a lot of code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but wanted to add a graph of the input data.  I don't see anything out of order (i.e. non-reproducable):

[image]